# Show error text if button clicked and input text empty in vue 3 scrupt setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logic, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I am new to Vue 3 and making a Vue 3 project.
I am facing a problem showing error text if the button clicks and the input text empty in Vue 3 script setup.

My logic is that-

1. I created a variable called `clicked` and I use this variable to listen to an event inside the HTML button `<button @click="clicked"></button>`.
2. I used a conditional rendering to tell if input (`memberName`) is empty and the button is clicked then show an error message. If the input is filled and clicked on button, do not show the error message.

But it's not working, and I have another problem that is the "error messages" is displaying even before the button is clicked which means when I arrive at the page, the error message is already there.
**I want the error message to appear only after the button is clicked.**

This is my GitHub if you want to see directly where is the problem: https://github.com/Darkheadbanger/wildCodeSchool_project

This my code-

**theForm.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, defineEmits } from "vue";

let memberName = ref("");
let clicked = ref(false); // Here

const emits = defineEmits(["addMember"]);

const addMember = () => {

  emits("addMember", memberName.value);
  memberName.value = "";

};

  <form
    class="member-form-container member-form-container__element"
    @submit.prevent="addMember"
  >
    <fieldset>
      <div>
        <div class="add-name">
          <label for="addName" class="label-name">Nom de l'Argonaute</label>
          <input
            id="addName"
            type="text"
            class="inputName"
            placeholder="Charlampos"
            v-model="memberName"
          />
        </div>
        <!-- showMore : pas de texte -->
        <!-- !showMore : texte -->
        <div
          v-if="memberName === '' && clicked ? !showMore : showMore"
          :style="showMore ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
        > <!--Here--!>
          <p class="error error__element error__element--modifier">
            Désolé, vous devez remplir le formulaire du nom!
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- <div v-if="memberName === '' ? 'hidden' : showMe">
          <p class="error error__element error__element--modifier">
            Désolé, vous devez remplir le formulaire du nom!
          </p>
        </div> -->
      </div>
      <!-- showMe true rendered -->
      <!-- !showMe false not rendered -->
      <button
        @click="clicked"
        type="submit"
        value="submit"
        class="button-add button-add__element button-add__element--modifier"
      > <!--Here--!>
        <!-- @click.prevent="addMember" -->
        Ajouter un membre
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

And I add another component to push the input values to local storage, here I don't want to put all the codes including the local storage

**TheMain.vue**

```
<script setup>

let crewArray = ref([{},]);
const addMember = (memberNameValues) => {
  console.log("hello", memberNameValues);
  // const notIdentical = crewArray.value.map(
  //   (x) => x.name.indexOf(memberNameValues) === -1
  // );
  const notIdentical = crewArray.value.indexOf(memberNameValues) === -1;
  console.log(notIdentical);
  if (memberNameValues === "") {
    alert("Désolé, vous devez remplir le formulaire nom!");
  } else {
    if (!notIdentical) {
      // Ne fonctionne pas, je veux
      alert("Hello alert");
    } else {
      crewArray.value.push({
        id: randomIdGenerator(),
        name: memberNameValues.trim(),
        createdAt: createdDate,
      });
    }
  }

  crewArray.value.reverse();
};
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div
        class="containerForm containerForm__element containerForm__element--modifier"
      >
        <h2>Ajouter un(e) Argonaute</h2>
        <Form @add-member="addMember" />
      </div>

      <section class="container-member container-member__element">
        <h2>Membres de l'équipage</h2>
        <div class="ul-wrapper">
          <ul class="member-list-container member-list-container__element">
            <!-- <Member /> -->
            <Member
              v-for="crewMember in crewArray"
              :key="crewMember.id"
              :member="crewMember"
            />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
<button @click="clicked"></button>
```

Button is of type="submit"
which means that addMember is invoked only if button is clicked.
Also, i would define another ref, for example

```
 const error = ref(null)
```

You can check inside **addMember** if  **memberName.value** is not empty.
For example

```
   if(!memberName.value) {
    error.value = true 
    return 
    }
```

And then use it for conditional rendering.